# JQuery not updating the background-image of a <div> element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

When I hover over a picture on this page, I should be updating the larger div element's src attribute above to be the image url of the image I am currently hovering over.

My breakpoints reach up to the

> "$('#image').on('hover', function() {"

line, but won't actually set the url attribute of the div element on the next line. Any pointers?

```js
function upDate(previewPic) {
  let newUrl = previewPic.src;
  $('#image').on('hover', function() {
    $('#image').attr("url", newUrl);
  });
};
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="image">
  Hover over an image below to display here.
</div>

<img alt="Batter is ready" class="preview" onmouseout="unDo()" onmouseover="upDate(this)" src="https://cdn.sallysbakingaddiction.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/moist-chocolate-cupcakes-7.jpg">

<img alt="Perfect Baking" class="preview" onmouseout="unDo()" onmouseover="upDate(this)" src="https://cdn.sallysbakingaddiction.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/moist-chocolate-cupcakes-6.jpg">

<img alt="Yummy yummy cup cake" class="preview" onmouseout="unDo()" onmouseover="upDate(this)" src="https://cdn.sallysbakingaddiction.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/moist-chocolate-cupcakes-5.jpg">
```

Comment: `img` has `src` attribute, not `url`. Change in your JavaScript

Comment: you can directly not set image to div, either use img tag or use other property of div css like image background.

Comment: In you function upDate you are just setting an eventListener for another element. Is this what you want to do? Don't you want to create + append/insert that into to the "#image" div? And as @Anton pointed out, there is no url attribute on a div element. Ofc you can define one if you really want this, but you should use a "img" element with "src" attribute.

Comment: Also you are using an inline event handler (`onmouseover`) to then assign another event handler (`.on('hover')`, this time on the `image` element, which is probably not your intent. Furthermore in the code you have provide there is an error in that `unDo` is not defined.

Comment: @DincaAdrian this was an assignment and I was told not to edit any of the html/css, just strictly the .js using jquery

Comment: @JimmyBlundell I missed you did need to change the background. I updated my answer to reflect that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Remove all inline event handlers
2. Add mouseenter and leave handlers
3. Access the css property

Divs do not have URLs

Also I moved the preview to not have to scroll too far down

```js
$(".preview").on("mouseenter",function() {
  $("#image").css({"background-image": `url(${this.src})`}); // this.src is the DOM notation for the source of the image you are hovering
})  
$(".preview").on("mouseleave",function() {
  $("#image").css({"background-image": "" })
})
```

```css
#image { 

height: 500px }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<img alt="Batter is ready" class="preview" src="https://cdn.sallysbakingaddiction.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/moist-chocolate-cupcakes-7.jpg" height="50">

<img alt="Perfect Baking" class="preview" src="https://cdn.sallysbakingaddiction.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/moist-chocolate-cupcakes-6.jpg" height="50">

<img alt="Yummy yummy cup cake" class="preview" src="https://cdn.sallysbakingaddiction.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/moist-chocolate-cupcakes-5.jpg" height="50">

<div id="image">
  Hover over an image above to display here.<br/>
</div>
```

Comment: "this.src" is just referring to the div though, right? not the actual image I hover over below it?

Comment: this.src is the source of the actual image you are hovering. It comes from the $(".preview") - the jQuery syntax is `$(this).prop("src")`

Comment: Ahh, I had assumed "this" came from the #image element

Comment: `$( ".preview" ).hover( function(){$("#image").css({"background-image":`url(${this.src})`});});` - Sorry, my markdown is ugly, but this is what worked for me. Thanks! I had my "image" and "img" elements mixed up was a big reason at the start.

Answer (score 1):

You try to set the url (not a valid attribute) of a div. What you actually want to do is to set the background URL of the div. Check my snippet for a hint into the right direction.

Also dont add another event listener inside the update function.

```js
function upDate(previewPic) {
  let newUrl = previewPic.src;
  document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + newUrl + ')';
}

function unDo(abc) {
  document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundImage = 'url()';
}
```

```css
#image {
  width: 100px;
  height: 120px;
  background-size: 100px 120px;
}
```

```html
<div id="image">
  Hover over an image below to display here.
</div>

<img alt="Batter is ready" class="preview" width="50" height="60" onmouseout="unDo()" onmouseover="upDate(this)" src="https://cdn.sallysbakingaddiction.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/moist-chocolate-cupcakes-7.jpg">

<img alt="Perfect Baking" class="preview" width="50" height="60" onmouseout="unDo()" onmouseover="upDate(this)" src="https://cdn.sallysbakingaddiction.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/moist-chocolate-cupcakes-6.jpg">

<img alt="Yummy yummy cup cake" class="preview" width="50" height="60" onmouseout="unDo()" onmouseover="upDate(this)" src="https://cdn.sallysbakingaddiction.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/moist-chocolate-cupcakes-5.jpg">
```

Comment: didnt pay attention to the styling @mplungjan fixed it. Thanks for your comment.